# The quotient of homogeneous polynomial on a smooth projective curve is meromorphic if the denominator is not identically zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Suppose $X \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ is a smooth projective curve.
Why is $G/H$ a meromorphic function on $X$ if $G$ and $H$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ and $H$ does not vanish identically on $X$.

It's been a while since I did Riemann surfaces, so I forgot what kind of approach should be used. I was initially thinking that perhaps Bezout would be useful, but now I'm doubting that.
Should one explicitly do something with the homogenous function $F(x,y,z)$ which defines $X$ (and then embeds it into $\mathbb{CP}^n$.  Or perhaps I should do something with affine patches or charts and show that $G/H$ has no essential singularities. But then again, I'm not sure how to show that all singularities are either poles or removable.

I was also thinking about the fact that $G/H$ being meromorphic, means that it's holomorphic when extended to the Riemann sphere $C_{\infty}$ and not the constant $\infty$ function. The latter is clear, as $H$ is not identically zero on $X$, but then again I'd have no idea how to show that the map to $C_{\infty}$ would be holomorphic.

I used the search function here as well, but I didn't really find posts tackling the same problem, so I hope it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Prove that $X/Z,Y/Z$ are meromorphic (assuming that the curve is not contained in $Z=0$) then look at $G(X/Z,Y/Z,1)/H(X/Z,Y/Z,1)$

Comment: But $G$ and $H$ are $n-$variate polynomials, not 3 per se. Do you then mean that all the other variables are set to 0?

Comment: And how do you deal with the points then of the curve that are contained in $Z=0$?